# How to write pandas into file without quotes

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to write pandas into txt file by running `df.to_csv("file.txt",header=None, index=None, sep=" ")`, but the file looks like:

> __label__9 , "sentence 1"
>
> __label__5 , "sentence 2"

How can I clean the quotes around my sentence?

I have tried

```
df.to_csv("file.txt",header=None, index=None, sep=" ", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

but I got:

> _csv.Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set

After reading documents, I still not clear about escapechar. What escapechar should I set for my data? Any help would be appreciated.

My data looks like:

> __label__9 , which movies was Maurice Renard the writer of ?

Comment: @Sirul Li post few lines of you data that you try to save

Comment: Works for me (both with and without `csv.QUOTE_NONE`) with a basic sample dataframe - this is probably to do with the data you're using.

Comment: Have you tried `escapechar='\\'`. Backslash is at least the usual suspect for things like this :-)

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi I have posted.

Answer (score 5):

Don't try to convert to csv and then to text file instead directly convert it.

```
np.savetxt('file.txt', df.values, fmt = "%s")
```

This worked for me and I got the text file in **fast-text** format.

Comment: Worked for me as well